# 「Apache」について教えてください。

Tags: apache, hadoop

webサーバーの Apache という存在はしっておりまして、何度か使用したこともあります。
ただ、Apache Hadoop というものもあるのですが、このHadoopの前にくっついているApacheとは何でしょうか？

webサーバーのApacheと同じ意味なのでしょうか？

ご存じの方いらっしゃいましたら教えて頂けると幸いです。

Answer (score 14, accepted):

ここで言うApacheとはApache Software Foundation（アパッチソフトウェア財団）の事です。WEBサーバーとして有名なのはApache HTTP Serverですね。Apache Software FoundationはHTTP Serverの開発からスタートしましたが、今ではHTTP Server以外にも数十のオープンソースプロダクトを運営しています。Apache Hadoopもその内のひとつです。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます！とてもわかりやすく理解できました。